# sqlplus -s username@conn_str/pw works differently in 11g /rhel6 and 21c/rhel8

Tags: linux, sqlplus, oracle11gr2, oracle21c

sqlplus command works differently in 11g /rhel6 and 21c/rhel8

In rhel6 batch server with 11.2 oracle client below command just works fine connecting to database
sqlplus username@connection_string/password
But in a new rhel8 batch server with 21.5 oracle client same above command does not work and it in turn prompt for a password
But the below command works in both the servers and versions
sqlplus username/password@connection_string
Why is this difference?
We are upgrading from rhel6 to rhel8 along with oracle client from 11g to 21c and we have many ksh shell scripts which has code using username@connection_string/password and when it is run in new server it is not connecting to database and prompts for password.
Is there any setting that I am missing or is it just different in different versions of oracle client and RHEL versions?

Comment: sqlplus username@connection_string/password --> works only in rhel6 and oracleclient11.2 sqlplus username/password@connection_string --> works in both rhel8 and rhel6 and oracle 11gand 21c

Comment: Ideally scripts would use a connection method that did not expose passwords. Also it might be a good idea to use `sqlplus -l` to prevent it from reprompting.